# MS Access 2007 pull data record from a different table to auto populate fields

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am making a `subreport` in `MS Access 2007` for a `detail` table. 
I would like to create a `combo-box` on this `subreport` that pulls `t_item.item_id` & `t_item.description` from the `t_item` table. I then want it to pull the data from the chosen record into the `MS Access subreport` in order to populate `read-only` fields. These `read-only` fields will then be used to populate their corresponding fields on `t_detail`. Note that `t_item` is not the `master` table to this `detail` table.

Users will then be able to fill in the missing data that only exists on `t_detail` and create the new record.

I have successfully created the `combo-box` and successfully populated it with `t_item.item_id` and `t_item.description`, but I have been unable to force any additional fields to pull in data from the same record. See below.

[image: Image of Form as Currently Exists]

Ideally, all of the information that already exists on `t_item` for this record should automatically populated the fields in this snippet. The only ones left blank for the users to enter will be `Net Weight` and `Package Count`since there is no way to know those values ahead of time.

Here is the query that is pulling up that combo box:

`SELECT t_item.[Item ID], t_item.[Description] FROM t_item;`

I've attempted to change the control source for the remaining fields, but nothing I have tried so far has successfully caused them to auto populate.

A short list of my attempts:

`=[t_item].[Item ID]`

`=[t_item].[HACCP] -- or whatever is appropriate`

My research has led me to an Access DB `Macro` that uses the `SearchForRecord` action and this `where condition`

`="[Customer ID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))`

However, I have no idea exactly what this does or how to modify it to suit my purposes. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure ig i got your question right. You want to populate rest of fields according to value selected in the combobox?

Comment: Yes I would like to populate the fields between HACCP and Net Weight